# ElasticSearch Count Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have JSON data like following in ES cluster,

```
"subjectData": {
   "caseA": [
      "na",
      "Mechanical Engineering",
      "Electrical and Electronic Engineering Technologies/Technicians, Other"
   ],
   "caseB": [
      "Mechanical Engineering",
      "Electrical Engineering Technologies/Technicians",
      "na"
   ],
   "caseC": [
      "Engineering",
      "Engineering Technologies and Engineering-related Fields",
      "Military Science, Leadership and Operational Art"
   ]
}
```

Now I need to query how many data having NA + some other subject values. Hence I need the query that can count the set of data having subjectData.fourdigit: NA + some other values, like,

```
GET mycluster/data/_count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "subjectData.fourdigit: \"na\" AND  subjectData.fourdigit: \"values other than NA\""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can use query like,

```
GET mucluster/data/_count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "subjectData.fourdigit: \"na\" AND  subjectData.fourdigit: \"Mechanical Engineering\""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which results in,

```
{
   "count": 2933,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 6,
      "successful": 6,
      "failed": 0
   }
}
```

But this is for one particular value, subjectData.fourdigit: \"Mechanical Engineering\", this cluster having more than 1000 values like this.

I need to frame it generic because I have millions of data and all those data having different subjectData.fourdigit values(1000s in count).

Any help/suggestion/idea would be very useful.